# Named Cache Vs Regions

Tags: appfabric-cache

I have a following requirement:

1) my cache framework should support Global cache and Application wise(based on country in which application is deployed) cache.

2) Global cache will contains the shared objects for all the applications

3) For the application wise cache, should I use named cache or Regions?  And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regions offer searching capabilities, but by limiting cached objects to a single cache host, the use of regions presents a trade-off between functionality and scalability.

Named cache, also referred to as a cache is the default container that spans all cache hosts in the cluster. Even, if there is a limit of 128 named caches, we can find a way to bypass this limit by using a prefix in your cache key.